# Angular Child component not emitting result to Parent

Tags: angular

I am trying to emit a child component value, but I'm confused how to pass the selection from the child to the parent. The child works fine, but no data is being passed to the parent. As I understand it I don't need to declare an event emitter- just use the @Output() annotation. Is that not correct?

WORKS (I can see the lgselected property change):

Child HTML:

```
{{lgselected.shortName}}
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="lgselected">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of lglist$" [value]="s">{{s.shortName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Child TS

```
lgselected: LicenseGroup;
```

DOESNT WORK (no console output when I change the child):

parent html:

```
<lgselector (lgselected)="lg"></lgselector>
```

parent component:

```
@Input() set lg(lg: LicenseGroup) {
    this._lg = lg;
    console.log('lg updated: ' + this._lg.id)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Child component

First of all you need to set `lgselected` as `@Output()` and `EventEmmiter()`

```
@Output() lgselected = new EventEmmiter();
```

Then you need to `emit` value on `(changes)`

So you will add it to the `mat-select`

```
<mat-select (change)="change($event)">
```

Then you can set up the `change` method in child component

```
change(event) {
  console.log(event);
  lgselected.emit(event);
}
```

### Parent component

In parent component just call method on emit

```
<lgselector (lgselected)="somethingChanged($event)"></lgselector>
```

Create this method in `*.component.ts`

```
somethingChanged(event) {
   console.log(event);
}
```

You don't need `@Input()` here.

For better understanding of components interaction take a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Does this actually work? Does `LicenseGroup` need to have an `emit` function on it? Does this compile?